# Optional many to many relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to produce an optional many to many relationship in rails?

I have a `Client` model and a `ClientManager` model - And I want a `Client` to have 0, 1 or many `client_managers`. But I'd also like a `Clientmanger` to be able to have 0, 1 or more `clients`. Is this possible? And how?

Using rails 5.

Updated for clarity/purpose: I want clientmanagers, to be able to manage multiple clients, or even none. And clients to be able to be managed by 0, 1 or multiple client-managers

Comment: Why can't you use just `has_many :client_managers` ?

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please include you current models as well. By default , a ``has_many`` relation can have zero associated objects.

Comment: @AlexKojin If i just use has_many :client_managers, how can a client-manager have more than one client to look after?

Comment: @raj As I understand it, a has_many relation can have zero associated objects. By typing in belongs_to :user, optional: true See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/870 - But maybe i am missing something

Comment: The best approach would be to create a ``ClientClientManagerRelation`` model through which you would be able to achieve this many to many association and configure it .

Comment: @raj Isn't that the same as a has_many :through? But just doing it more manually, allowing for a ClientManager row in the ClientClientManagerRelation table to have a null-value for instance? I wondered if there was a rails-way of doing this.

Comment: There is not going to be any null value when you do this. The ``Relation`` model will have a ``client_id`` column and ``manager_id`` column. A relationship is established with entering values there. By the way, this is the rails way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an NxN relationship, you should create another model that belongs to both Client and ClientManager. Let's call it Management, for instance:

```
rails g model Management client:references client_manager:references
```

That would generate something like this:

```
class Management < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :client_managers
end
```

and then, on your Client model:

```
  has_many :managements
  has_many :client_managers :through => :managements
```

and on your ClientManager:

```
  has_many :managements
  has_many :clients :through => :managements
```

Hope this helps you figure out. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! Will a many-to-many relationship like this not fail if a client has no manager then?

Comment: No! If you try to access some client.client_managers, it will return nil if doesn't have any. Also, the @geoandri answer is good aproach that may work too. I'm not familiarized rsrs, but this links gives a good example: https://coderwall.com/p/i4c8mg/has_and_belongs_to_many-habtm-associations-in-rails-4

Comment: Think I got it now. It wont even create a row in the intermediary/join-table, because there isnt a need for a relationship, if it hasn't got a client-manager - therefore it won't throw an error - there's nothing to be handled so to speak. 

Marking this as the answer, since it seems from other posts out there, that this is the most common way of doing many-to-many - and allows for other rows in the intermediary table

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, other post why you should never use HABTM relationship, like in the other answer: http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association.

Your models would be

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :managers
end

class Manager< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a straightforward many-to-many relationship with `has_many through` relation between `Client` and `ClientManager` data models. For this, you need to setup 3 tables in your db `clients`, `client_managers`, `projects`

```
# models/client.rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :client_managers, through: :projects
end

# models/project.rb
# projects table schema should have- client_id:integer client_manager_id:integer
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :client_manager
end    

# models/client_manager.rb
class ClientManager < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :clients, through: :projects
end
```

**Access**

`Client.last.client_managers` gives 0, 1 or many client_managers associated with `Client.last`

`ClientManager.last.clients` gives 0, 1 or many clients associated with `ClientManager.last`

[more info here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and elaborative examples of code. It all makes sense now!