# Multiple Associations With the Same Table (Many-to-Many) Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord, relationship

I am trying to figure out the best way to accomplish a relationship and having some trouble. I have come across a few articles that somewhat address what I am looking to do but not quite.

I have a Users model and a Tickets model. Both are joined through a UserTickets model so I am able to assign multiple Users to a ticket. What I would like to do is segment the Users assigned to a Ticket into requesters and agents. The Users model does not have any columns to declare if the user is a requester or agent, rather I have is_admin, is_customer, etc. I think what I need is along the lines of [Ruby On Rails - many to many between the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098441/ruby-on-rails-many-to-many-between-the-same-table) but not quite.

Ideally, I'd like to have my Tickets table take agent_id's (user_id from User class) and requester_id's (user_id from User class) rather than the general user_id's (user_id from User class which combines all the users into one group). I would assume would still allow me to call @current_user.tickets to pull all the tickets that are assigned to that user.

**Here is my Users model:**

```
  has_many :user_tickets
  has_many :support_tickets, through: :user_tickets
```

**Here is my Tickets model:**

```
  has_many :user_tickets
  has_many :users, through: :user_tickets
```

**Here is my UserTickets join model:**

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :support_ticket
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional many to many relationship in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888515/optional-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

@Skylar,

1) If your goal is to assign multiple Users to a ticket? Because this doesn't require a many-to-many relationship. You just need to a one-many relationship and a boolean attribute `agent?` on User model. You can even create am Agent model that uses User model, if you like this better.

2) However, if you wanted to create a many-to-many relationship check out [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). The Rails documentation is better than I write. See section 2.6 The has_and_belongs_to_many Association.

Solution to 1)

Models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets, class_name: :Ticket, foreign_key: :agent_id

  def agent?
    self.agent
  end
end

class Agent < User
  default_scope { where(agent: true) }
end

class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :agent, class_name: :User
end
```

Migrations

```
class CreateTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tickets do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :agent, index: true
      t.string :event_name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Dan, After looking at 2.6 in the link you sent over and using that diagram as an example.. I'd want two groups of parts on assemblies... for example metal parts or wooden parts both pulling from part_id in the parts model. The declaration as to whether or not the part is wooden or metal would be decided by the user that enters it into the assembly because there is no identifiable columns in the parts table describing what type it is.

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Comment: Not really I'm afraid. I don't know how to setup the model to account for what I'm looking to do.

Comment: You just need a Ticket model, a User model and an Agent model as described above.

Your Ticket migration needs to have two references; one for User and another for Agent.

This way, you can create a Ticket with Agent and later add User (buyer) and each sold ticket would have two references. You would control this in User model and/or you can create PORO as Service Object to handle it.

Comment: Another solution would be creating a join table `Ticketing` which would be joining ticket_id, user_id and agent_id. It would has its own id and don't forget the timestamps.

You would need to create this migration manually and have the 3 models as  mentioned above.